# How can I make a table (or part of a table) fill the rest of the container, height-wise

Tags: javascript, html, tcpdf

Basically I'm trying to set up a layout to print bills with tcpdf and I want the bottom part to take up the space remaining after I print the products and services and stuff. I'm wondering if I can make it do that without calculating its height with javascript.

The problem I have with javascript is that I can't just take their height and do some magic math to make them fit because they don't exist in a window. I'd have to somehow calculate the height of the products table based on the number of rows which might not be hard but what do I do if something exceeds its cell width and takes up two of them?

Help's totally apreciated.

i'm not adding code because there's really not much to add, it's just feeding HTML to the tcpdf function.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to make the bottom row of a table grow.

Alternate solutions:

- Wrap the `table` in a `div` and set it's height to `100%`. The `div` will then fill the background. If you make the table opaque, it will look right unless you want something like "extend column borders to the bottom".
- HTML is not a good format to create paged output. HTML has no real concept of "page size", it's hard to influence where a page break should (or should not) occur, etc. Instead of trying to manipulate the output remotely, try to drive the TCPDF framework directly. Create PDF page objects, draw the table outline over the full height, start rendering cells until a page is full, start new page, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Trying the first idea since the last cell has no columns just some info onthe product and delivery. Will update soon.

Comment: First one doesn't seem to work. It looks like TCPDF is ignoring the div's height alltogether. even on a test case printing just a 200px height div with a border it only prints a line.  `'<div style="width: 100%; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; height: 200px;"></div>
`  prints a straight line